# Rust match expected different operator than =>

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and was messing about with match {} and enumerations. I had this code, but for some reason when I try to build it in cargo I get this error message:

> error: expected one of `!`, `.`, `::`, `;`, `?`, `{`, `}`, or an
> operator, found `=>`

=> is the operator used for match, as I've seen in the Rust doc book and Rust by example. I'm using VSCode, with the rustup extension, and compiling it with cargo, which has never been an issue with other Rust programs I've messed about with, so I'm wondering what's going wrong here.

```
enum Coins {
    Penny,
    Pound,
}

fn check_coin(coin: Coins) -> i32 {
    match {
        Coins::Penny => {
            println!("That's a penny!");
            1
        }
        Coins::Pound => {
            println!("That's a pound!");
            100
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there should be a `,` after (or at least between) match arms.

Comment: Not when the arms are blocks.

Comment: If you think the question isn't useful, you can delete it, assuming that no one has written an answer yet. If you can't delete it, don't worry about it, you don't need to add commentary to the top of the question saying why the question isn't useful.

Comment: @cigien `no one has written an answer yet` => why do you think so? This question has 2 answer, one with +1 (currently +2).

Comment: The Rust way is to `impl Display for Coins` here instead of combining a "check" (convert?) function and display. Then you can do `println!("That's a {coin}!")` and it works.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `match` takes an expression. Because you didn't give it an expression, as far as rustc is concerned *you're giving it a block-expression*:

```rust
match ({/*your code here*/}) {
    ...
}
```

Therefore it's in a parsing mode for a block. In that context `Coins::Penny` is valid, but what's valid after it is one of "!, ., ::, ;, ?, {, }":

- `!` would be for a macro
- `.` would be for an attribute or method call
- `::` for an other namespace
- `;` for an end of statement
- `?` for a try-expression
- `{` for a keyword
- `}` for an end of block

(actually `(` should also be valid, not sure why it's not suggested).

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like such a doofus forgetting the expression! I'm new to Rust but not to coding in general, so I think I just had a brain fart.

Answer (score 3):

Match needs an argument

```
fn check_coin(coin: Coins) -> i32 {
    match coin {
        Coins::Penny => {
            println!("That's a penny!");
            1
        },
        Coins::Pound => {
            println!("That's a pound!");
            100
        }
    }
}
```